# Contenteditable automatically applying CSS to entered text

Tags: jquery, css, html

Is there a way to disable the affect of CSS like text-transform on text entered using contentedtiable?

On my page "CERTIFICATE PROGRAM" is displayed as text-transform is set to uppercase. 
The actual data entered was: Certificate Program.

When I type in the field via contenteditable any text added is automatically uppercase.

Setting contenteditable CSS to text-transform:none; doesn't work because then the display text is: Certificate Program and I want "CERTIFICATE PROGRAM"

Can I use my CSS settings for display purposes, but not affect newly entered text?

What's happening now: TEXT: CERTIFICATE PROGRAMS, HTML:

```
<section id="name+degree+96" contenteditable="true">Certificate PrograMS</section>
```

What I want: TEXT: CERTIFICATE PROGRAMS, HTML:

```
<section id="name+degree+96" contenteditable="true">Certificate Programs</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L2XGV/), the original text value isn't affected by `text-transform`, because it changes only the way you see text (edit the text and then click somewhere).

I don't know what you want, the question isn't that clear, but..

If you want to get rid of the uppercase text on that section just override it with:

```
section[contenteditable] {
   text-transform: none;
}
```

If you want to get rid of the uppercase text while editing it:

```
section[contenteditable]:focus {
   text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: `none` is the initial default value, not `normal`.

Comment: Thanks! The :focus is what I needed. Now when I enter text it's displayed as capitalized, but in the code it's case is as entered.

Answer (score 1):

just override the previous css rule, e.g.

```
section[contenteditable] {
   text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I want to keep the display text uppercase. Just want consistent case for what is saved. I edited the question for clarity.